# «Ледяной горою айсберг из тумана вырастает»

Tags: значение-слов, тавтология

Является ли словосочетание "ледяной горою айсберг" тавтологией?

Answer (score 1):

Вот значение слова [**айсберг**](https://slovar.cc/enc/bolshoy-rus/1692357.html) в различных словарях.

Большой российский энциклопедический словарь:
(англ. *iceberg*), отколовшиеся от ледника **массивы различной формы**; может быть на плаву или сидеть на мели. Высота над поверхностью воды до 70 м (Арктика), 100 м (Антарктика); б. ч. объёма под водой.

Энциклопедический словарь:
Отколовшийся от ледника дрейфующий **ледяной массив** с глубоко погруженной подводной частью.

Современный энциклопедический словарь:
(английское *iceberg*, от голландского *ijsberg*, слово скандинавского происхождения), ледяная гора, **крупная глыба ледникового льда**, плавающая в море, приледниковом озере или сидящая на мели.

Ледяная гора — это дословный перевод на русский язык.
Посмотрите на [фотографии айсбергов](https://fishki.net/24815-krasivye-foto-ajsbergov-109-foto.html) — многие из них похожи на что угодно (колонны, арки, плоские полосатые камни, изумрудные и голубые кристаллы, плавучие белые острова...), но только не на гору.
Думаю, что во фразе нет тавтологии, а есть **сравнение** большущего айсберга с горой.

*Айсберги имеют причудливые формы, иногда они схожи по форме с ледяными кристаллами, а порой напоминают столбы и футбольные поля* (Е. Ананьева. Опасная природа).